# How can I print the indexPath of a TableView cell containing a UITextField from one of the TextField delegate functions?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates, uitextfield

Here is where I generate my custom cells, which store an attribute called "indexPath". Furthermore, each cell contains a UITextField. The textfield delegate function is below. Both of these functions exist within the same ViewController.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ReusableCell", for: indexPath) as! BuyerCell

    cell.nameField.delegate = self
    cell.indexPath = indexPath
    cell.nameField.text = potentialBuyers[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Here is the TextField delegate function. I need to print the cell's indexPath from within the delegate function.

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    print("called textFieldDidEndEditing")

    //I need to print the cell's indexPath here 

}
```

Comment: Your text field delegate should probably exist within your custom cell.  The custom cell can then use a protocol to notify the view controller through delegation of whatever is required.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow. I can think of multiple ways to do this, without even testing these ideas.

**Subclassing**

Have your own `UITextField` subclass, and put a variable there to hold the `IndexPath` object, and in `cellForRow`, store the current `IndexPath` to that textField.

So in your textField delegate `textFieldDidEndEditing`, you can either change the type `UITextField` to your own class like `MyTextField`. 
OR you can just cast it like:

```
if let customTextField = textField as? MyTextField
```

**Storing row as TAG**

This one is much simpler, but perhaps only limited to a single section tableView. If you are using a single section, then you can just store the `row` of the `IndexPath` in your `cellForRow` to the `TAG` property of the textField.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below.

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    let gpoint = textField.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: tableView)
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: gpoint)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would decouple the text field delegate from the view controller and either use an your own delegation protocol between the cell and your view controller or, as I show below, use a closure to handle the event from the cell in the view controller

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ReusableCell", for: indexPath) as! BuyerCell
    let buyer = potentialBuyers[indexPath.row]

    cell.nameEditedHandler = { textField in
        // Do something - you still have access to indexPath, cell and buyer
    }

    cell.nameField.text = buyer
    return cell
}
```

In your `BuyerCell` class -

```
class BuyerCell: UITableViewCell {
    var nameField: UITextField!

    var nameEditedHandler: ((UITextField)->Void)?

    func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.nameField.delegate = self
    }
}

extension BuyerCell: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        self.nameEditedHandler?(textField)
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the .tag property of UITextfeild

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ReusableCell", for: indexPath) as! BuyerCell

     cell.nameField.delegate = self
     cell.indexPath = indexPath
     cell.nameField.text = potentialBuyers[indexPath.row]
     cell.nameField.tag = indexPath.row // here assign the indexpath
     return cell
}
```

Now use the delegate method of UITextField

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
      print(textField.tag) // here you print the index
      print("called textFieldDidEndEditing")
      let indexPath = IndexPath.init(row: textField.tag, section: 0) //create indexpath from tag

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ReusableCell", for: indexPath) as! BuyerCell

cell.nameField.delegate = self
cell.indexPath = indexPath
cell.nameField.text = potentialBuyers[indexPath.row]
// add tag for the textField
cell.nameField.tag = indexPath.row
return cell

}
```

Now in textFieldDelegate Method get your cell and cell.indexPath like this

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    print("called textFieldDidEndEditing")

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: textField.tag, section: 0)) as! BuyerCell
    print(cell.indexPath)

}
```